# Android Studio - SQLiteDatabase.java error imports

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, studio, java-import

tengo un problema con mi clase java SQLiteDatabase
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debido a que los imports no están siendo reconocidos no puedo inicar mi base de datos para mi proyecto,
he actualizado mi android studio a la última versión(4.0.0) al igual que el gradle build.

Este es la clase donde empiezo a correr mi base de datos

```
package com.example.proyectomovil.data
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase


open class ClaseBase {

public fun CadenaConexion():String{
    return "/data/data/com.example.proyec``tomovil.data/colegio.db"
}


public fun CrearBaseDatos() {
    var odb: SQLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
        CadenaConexion(),
        null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY)

    odb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PROFESOR(" +
            "iddocente int primary key, nombre varchar(45), apellidos varchar(55)," +
            "usuario varchar(10), clave varchar(8), idcurso int)")
    odb.execSQL("insert into PROFESOR values (1, Juan, Chalco, prfJC, 12345, 12)")

}
}
```

Y esta es mi clase DAO

```
package com.example.proyectomovil.data

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import com.example.proyectomovil.Beans.Profesor

class ProfesorDAO:ClaseBase() {

init{
    super.CrearBaseDatos()
}

public fun RegistrarProfesor(pProf: Profesor, pAccion:String){
    var odb:SQLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.CadenaConexion(),
        null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY)
    var pContenido:ContentValues= ContentValues()

    pContenido.put("iddocente", pProf.iddocente)
    pContenido.put("nombre", pProf.nombre)
    pContenido.put("apellidos", pProf.apellidos)
    pContenido.put("usuario", pProf.usuario)
    pContenido.put("clave", pProf.clave)
    pContenido.put("idcurso", pProf.idcurso)
    if(pAccion=="N") {
        var oresult = odb.insert("PROFESOR", null, pContenido).toInt()
        if (oresult == -1) {

        }
    }
    /*else if(pAccion=="N") {
        var oresult = odb.update("PROFESOR", null, ).toInt()
        if (oresult == -1) {

        }
    }*/
}
public fun Login(user:String, pas:String):Boolean{
    var odb:SQLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.CadenaConexion(),
    null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY)
    val query = "select * from PROFESOR where usuario = $user and clave = $pas"
    val cursor = odb.rawQuery(query, null)
    if(cursor.count<=0){
        cursor.close()
        return false
    }
    cursor.close()
    return true
}
}
```

Aquí llamo el DAO para validar el usuario y contraseña

```
package com.example.proyectomovil.Activities

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.proyectomovil.R
import com.example.proyectomovil.data.ClaseBase
import com.example.proyectomovil.data.ProfesorDAO
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_profesor_login.*

class ProfesorLogin : AppCompatActivity() {



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profesor_login)

    ebtn_Ingresar.setOnClickListener{
        var oProfesorDAO:ProfesorDAO=ProfesorDAO()
        if(oProfesorDAO.Login(txtUsuario.text.toString(), 
    txtContra.text.toString())){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ingreso con éxito", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Usuario o contraseña incorrecto", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
}
```

Este es mi build:gradle de Project:ProyectoMovil

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
   all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Y este mi build:gradle de Module:app

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.proyectomovil"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
}
```

El problema fue antes de que actualizará mi android, además descargue bastantes paquetes por el SDK manager pero igual presento este problema.

Comment: Hola puedes poner el código de como estas cargando tu base de datos y también la dirección exacta de donde lo estas cargando, parece que el path no es el correcto.

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya he implementado los códigos de creación de base de datos y su llamado.

Comment: Agrega al menos tu build.gradle por favor

Comment: Ya los coloqué, gracias.